# carriage return for encoding

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ascii

Im trying to send ascii encoded message to a server.  My problem is coming in when I try to append the carriage return to the string

```
-(void)button2Pressed
{
    NSMutableString *mutableString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"h323name get"];

    [self sendStringCommand:mutableString];
}

-(void)sendStringCommand:(NSMutableString*)string
{    
    [string appendString:@"\\r"]; 

    NSLog(@"string %@ wtf",[string dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
    NSData * testData = [[NSData alloc]initWithBytes:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] length:sizeof([string dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding])];


    [socket  writeData:testData withTimeout:20 tag:1];  

}
```

currently this outputs this:

> string <68333233 6e616d65 20676574 5c72> wtf

which should be

> string <68333233 6e616d65 20676574 0d> wtf

Just plain /r did a new line hence the wtf characters after the data in the nslog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many backslashes.  Try this:

```
[string appendString:@"\r"];
```

Also, your creation of `testData` is completely wrong.  The way you are creating `testData` is passing a pointer to an `NSData` object as the "bytes" parameter, and passing the size of a pointer to an `NSData` as the "length" parameter.  You should just do this:

```
NSData *testData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: thank you that did work, idk what i was thinking when i tried that the first time and it didnt work???! o well thanks again, ill accept when it lets me